# What algorithm does Better Settlers use?

Tags: catan

I have been using [Better Settlers](http://www.bettersettlers.com/Generate.html) and found that it sets boards that have even probabilities. I would like to understand the algorithm used to generate the board layout, and how it achieves a "fair" setup.

Comment: Just an opinion on the very premise of "Better Settlers": I like the ueven probablilities, with good and bad spots on the map. The tension when going around the table in deployment is one of the best things with Settlers. The first player might get the best spot, but will likely have to cope with the worst spot also. I like the experience of trying to balance probablilities, blocking other players and getting a good mix of resources. Instead of copying "Better settlers" algorithms, I would think differently on how to generate interesting maps :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code for Better Settlers is open-source and can be found at [github.com/andrewflynn/bettersettlers](http://github.com/andrewflynn/bettersettlers). Not the easiest format to read on the algorithm, but hopefully that helps a little bit.

Also to answer Markus' concern above about taking away the tension of setup, Better Settlers still has that same tension (and arguably even more so because it's actually even more difficult to figure out what the best spots are).

The thing that Better Settlers tries to avoid is situations where combinations of starting positions are completely unbalanced. You still have the same pros/cons of placing first vs. last; it's just at the end of it, everyone stands a much better chance of still being in the game.

Comment: Specifically, you can read the placement file at bettersettlers/app/src/main/java/com/nut/bettersettlers/logic/PlacementLogic.java

Comment: any plans to create an iphone app?

Comment: as well as MapLogic.java which lays out the tiles (PlacementLogic.java lays out the "best" initial placement suggestions)

Comment: @AndrewFlynn any plans to create an iphone app?

Comment: Definitely! Unfortunately though Better Settlers is just a fun side project for me, so I don't get as much time to devote to it as I'd like and haven't had a chance to finish creating one. Hopefully one day though :)

Comment: @AndrewFlynn if you create an iphone app, let me know in advance (please post app release data over here). I would like to be the first user who downloads it :)